# will this OO win32API example work with multiple windows?

Tags: oop, winapi, api, friend, wndproc

i'm mainly focused on how this example uses wndproc as friend... im a little confused how it works and im just trying to figure out if and how this would work with more than one window

http://www.uta.fi/~jl/pguibook/api2oo.html

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Microsoft version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485838.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work with more than one window because it stores a pointer to the C++ object with the corresponding HWND:

```
Window *wPtr;
...
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0, (LONG_PTR) wPtr);
```

and the global `WndProc` then retrieves that pointer and calls the object's methods through it:

```
wPtr = (Window*) ::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0);
wPtr->WndProc(message, wParam, lParam);
```

(Note that the original code uses `SetWindowLong`, and hence won't work in a 64-bit program - I've changed the code above to use `SetWindowLongPtr`.)

Comment: Please change to SetWindowLongPtr - it works for 32 and 64 bit apps. SetWindowLong docs will tell you to change.

Comment: @Boofhead: I was quoting verbatim the code that @gizmo pointed at.  But you're right, code here on StackOverflow should be correct, so I've changed it.